# Should I Dispose System.Windows.Media.Pen?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.0, c#-4.0

Should I Dispose **`System.Windows.Media.Pen`** ?

It was usual to call the Dispose method of a `System.Drawing.Pen`.

Comment: Can you even do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If it's disposable, dispose it.

In this case, `System.Windows.Media.Pen` does not appear to be disposable.

Answer (score 0):

Anything that has a .Dispose() method (specifically anything that implements IDisposable) must be disposed.

So seeing the Media.Pen does not implement IDisposable you don't need to or cant', but just so you understand why and how to figure out if you should or shouldn't in the future...